# How does one run code in a Vue component only once per page (when more than one of the same component exists on that page)?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

So I have a Vue component which has two functions.  One attaches some data and populates various tags with that data, another gets the data from a json file and parses through it - applying it to the other function.

(pseudo-code ahead!)

```
mounted: function() {
  function listBuilder(data) { some code }
  $.get("some-json"), function (data) {
    [some code...]
    listBuilder(data);
  }
}
```

On the page itself, this component exists twice.

```
<section>
  <my-component type="map"></my-component>
</section>
<aside>  
  <my-component></my-component>
</aside>
```

One component renders out the data in map form, while the other renders it out as a list.  This all works just fine & dandy, except that on the map the data is rendered 2x - because, as you might have guessed, the component's logic is run twice - getting the json twice and processing it twice.

Is there a native "Vue" way to have (or designate) the code in the component to only run once on a page?  I have a rather (in my opinion), hacky way of avoiding this right now, by applying a property to one of the components ("dumb"), that essentially skips some of the logic via a check if that property exists.  I feel there has got to be a more elegant and native way to handle this, however, but have come up dry in my google searches.

Comment: I think your solution is to move the $.get out of the component and into a singleton. Having a view component bound to an http service is a bit of an anti-pattern and will make testing difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to have the component data loading moved to another parent element. Other way of doing this is to have one global store (like `vuex`) and then load the data out of it. This is just the type of problem `vuex` is solving. If you don't want to use `vuex` just use the browser's [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) it is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) and you can store all the data you need in it. It is session based so you won't need to load the information every time.

Comment: Thank you melanholly.  I'm marking your answer as the correct one, mostly because, for the time being, I'm taking the easy path (due to time constraints) and taking your advice and moving the logic up into the parent element (which seems to work just fine).  When I have more time I want to return to this and refactor it using Vuex as you, @peaceman and pinoyyid suggested.  I really appreciate the three of you chiming in and helping answer this!

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm sure you'll get different responses, but I would have to agree with @pinoyyid and suggest extracting http part into a service for start, and then I would implement Vuex ( centralized local data that can be fairly easily integrated with Vue ) and then use Vuex actions and getters to get and process data. This will completely separate your vue component from fetching and data processing. You will only fetch your data once and then use it as many times as you'd like. And last but not least testing will be possible unlike now.